# How do I make saltstack wait for 200 OK?

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following state:

```
healthy:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo 'True'
    - onlyif: "curl -I http://127.0.0.1:{{ port }} 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | awk '$2 ~ /200/ { print \"True\" }"
    - require:
      - docker: running
```

the problem is that it only checks once and then exits, how do I make it so that it waits for a certain timeout until it actually gets `200` otherwise exits?

Comment: You could set the timeout for curl:  `--connect-timeout` `--max-time`. Use `man curl` for more info.

Comment: @deathangel908 interesting, will try that one. :)

Comment: Point for putting me on the right direction, but I use `wget` instead since `curl` has no retry for connection refused. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
while $(curl -I http://localhost:8080/ 2> /dev/null | awk '/200 OK/
 { exit 1 }'); 
do count=$(expr $count + 1); sleep 1; [ "$count" -ge "60" ] && exit 1; done
```